# Почему слайдер slick не адаптируется после изменения ориентации устройства?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, slick.js

Здравсвтуйте!

[Есть](http://balqaragai.kz/banquet) сайт, на котором 2 слайдера slick jquery, отображается вроде адекватно на компьютере, но если зайти с мобильного устройства с портретной ориентацией, и далее сделать ее горизонтальной -вроде бы и тут все норм, но если вернуть обратно - адаптации не происходит, высота нижнего слайдера становиться такой, какой она была на ПК-версии, первый слайдер остается таким же каким был на ПК, но адаптирует только ширину экрана. Можете проверить через device toolbar в браузере, если Вы сделаете ширину экрана 415 - слайдеры будут отображаться криво, но если вы уменьшите размер, например, на 1 пиксель - слайдер адаптируется так как необходимо.
Вот код скриптов:

```
  function size_img(){
if(w.width() <= 415){
  img_item1.each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('mobile'));
  });
  img_item2.each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('mobile'));
  });
  img_item3.each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('mobile'));
  });
}
else if(w.width() <= 1024){
  img_item1.each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('mobile'));
  });
  img_item2.each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('pc'));
  });
  img_item3.each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('tablet'));
  });
}
else if(w.width() > 1024){
  img_item1.each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('pc'));
  });
  img_item2.each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('pc'));
  });
  img_item3.each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('pc'));
  });
}
```

}

size_img();

w.resize(function (){
    size_img();
  });

`$('.slider__foods').slick({
    focusOnSelect: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    prevArrow: $('#section4 .go__back'),
    nextArrow: $('#section4 .go__next'),
    centerMode: true,
    autoplay: true,
    responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        speed: 300,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 10000,
        centerMode: false,
        centerPadding: '0',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        variableWidth: false
      }
    }
    ]
    });
  $('.slider__atmosphere').slick({
    speed: 300,
    centerPadding: 35,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    prevArrow: $('#section7 .go__back'),
    nextArrow: $('#section7 .go__next'),
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          speed: 300,
          autoplay: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 10000,
          centerMode: false,
          centerPadding: '0',
          slidesToShow: 1,
          variableWidth: false
        }
      }
    ]
  });`

html:

`<div class="slider__foods">
            <div>
                <img data-pc="img/banquet/foods/bludo_1.jpg" data-mobile="img/banquet/foods/mobile/1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img data-pc="img/banquet/foods/bludo_2.jpg" data-mobile="img/banquet/foods/mobile/2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img data-pc="img/banquet/foods/bludo_3.jpg" data-mobile="img/banquet/foods/mobile/3.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img data-pc="img/banquet/foods/bludo_4.jpg" data-mobile="img/banquet/foods/mobile/4.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img data-pc="img/banquet/foods/bludo_5.jpg" data-mobile="img/banquet/foods/mobile/5.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img data-pc="img/banquet/foods/bludo_6.jpg" data-mobile="img/banquet/foods/mobile/6.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img data-pc="img/banquet/foods/bludo_7.jpg" data-mobile="img/banquet/foods/mobile/7.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img data-pc="img/banquet/foods/bludo_8.jpg" data-mobile="img/banquet/foods/mobile/8.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img data-pc="img/banquet/foods/bludo_9.jpg" data-mobile="img/banquet/foods/mobile/9.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img data-pc="img/banquet/foods/bludo_10.jpg" data-mobile="img/banquet/foods/mobile/10.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="arrows__slide">
            <div class="go__back">
                <span>листать влево</span>
            </div>
            <div class="go__next">
                <span>листать вправо</span>
            </div>
        </div>`

Comment: Желательно увидеть и код html, здесь сделаете рабочий код посмотрим

Comment: Дополнил вопрос html кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю зачем вы делаете несколько изображений для разных размеров? слайдер вполне нормально работает и не имеет никаких проблем с адаптивностью.

Вот пример работающего слайдера с js библиотекой slick.

```
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <button class="btn-unslick">Unslick</button>
        <button class="btn-add">Add Panel</button>
        <button class="btn-prev">Prev</button>
        <button class="btn-next">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div id="dashboard">
        <div class="panel">1</div>
        <div class="panel">2</div>
        <div class="panel">3</div>
        <div class="panel">4</div>
        <div class="panel">5</div>
        <div class="panel">6</div>
        <div class="panel">7</div>
        <div class="panel">8</div>
        <div class="panel">9</div>
        <div class="panel">10</div>
        <div class="panel">11</div>
        <div class="panel">12</div>
    </div>
</body>

#nav {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.panel {
    border: 10px solid #333;
    background: #ccc;
    height:200px;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 72px;
    text-align: center;
}

$(function () {
    var $panel = $('<div class="panel">13</div>');
    var slickOpts = {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        dots: true,
        prevArrow: '.btn-prev',
        nextArrow: '.btn-next'
    };
    // Init the slick
    $('#dashboard').slick(slickOpts);
    var slickEnabled = true;

    // Add panel
    $('.btn-add').on('click', function () {
        $('#dashboard').slickAdd($panel);
    });


    // Slick/Unslick
    $('.btn-unslick').on('click', function (e) {
        if (slickEnabled) {
            $('#dashboard').unslick();
            $(this).text('Slick');
            slickEnabled = false;
        } else {
            $('#dashboard').slick(slickOpts);
            $(this).text('Unslick');
            slickEnabled = true;
        }
    });

    // Re-slick
    $('.btn-slick').on('click', function () {
        $('#dashboard').slick(slickOpts);
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Изображений несколько для того, чтобы с мобилки не подгружать большие изображения, которые они в полном объеме посмотреть все-равно не смогут. Подключил у себя на локалке только одну фотку на слайд - все-равно ничего не изменилось.
То, что это распространенный слайдер и он корректно работает с адаптивностью я знаю, вопрос был в контексте моего сайта.

Comment: @ДимДим Ну значит проблема решена уже? И если вам помог мой ответ то поставьте пожалуйста птичку возле ответа.

Comment: Нет, проблема не решена.

Comment: может линк вашей страницы скажете? протестирую на разных размерах и скажу вам проблему? Если проблема в коде сайта а не в самом слайдере то так не как не помогу вам.

Comment: balqaragai.kz , линк был на слове "Есть"))))

Comment: Смотрю сайт, и хочу понять какой слайдер не работает при ориентации телефона? у меня в браузере слайдеры вашей первой страницы работают нормально

Comment: balqaragai.kz/banquet

Comment: И первый и второй слайдер. Попробуйте зайти по линку с телефона, сменить ориентацию, и далее вернуть обратно портретную ориентацию. На первом слайдере будут 5 изображений(маленьких) вместо одной. На втором будет либо будет ширина как при ПК-версии, либо картинка будет большая и видна не полностью.

Comment: У вас есть telegram? Давайте там спишемся?

Comment: Вот я сейчас использую device toolbar на google chrome и тут, если задать ширину 416(версия ПК), перейти на 415(включается версия мобильная, но слайды отображаются не так как надо) и если тут же сделать ширину 414 - все становиться так как нужно.

Comment: Я попробовал так как вы сказали и у меня все нормально отоброжалось, могу и скриншоты отправить Вам?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cibsonbxd99sio3/photo_2017-05-27_16-38-33.jpg?dl=0